# Reporting Utilization of Individual ResourcePool units

Tags: anylogic, resource-utilization

In Anylogic, How can I get statistics such as utilization of individual resource pool units? 
As the resourcePool.utilization() function returns the mean utilization for all units in the resource pool.
Is it possible to access the data of each resource pool unit? Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Updated Answer

There is an easier way to get the utilization for individual resource units:

1. Define a custom resource agent type, as explained [here](https://help.anylogic.com/topic/com.anylogic.help/html/_ProcessModeling/Resource_Type.html)
2. Set this new custom type for your resource pool as *New resource unit*
3. Add an empty population of this custom resource type (here named *myResources*)
4. In the resource pool under *Advanced/Population* set this empty population

Now you can access the individual resource pool units' utilization, with *x* as the index of the unit:

```java
myResources(x).getUtilization()
```

In order to keep track of more complex statistics, you might still need to use the more complicated solution of the original answer.

---

#### Original Answer:

You can build something yourself:

1. Use the *On seize* and *On release* code in the ressourcePool to notify your custom ressource Agent that it is active/not active. You can pass a message to the agent or call a function inside the agent.
2. The ressource agent can save its current state in a variable, statechart or similar.
3. You can then use the standard statistic module from the *Analysis* palette to aggregate the information, for example to get the individual agent's  utilization.

Comment: thank you for your answer!  I didn't understand how this information can be saved for each unit separately or how I could differentiate which data is related to which exact unit. Furthermore, I didn't exactly know what you meant by (notify your custom ressource Agent).

Comment: I found out that there is indeed an easier way to do it, although my original answer might be used when you need more then only utilization. Please check out the updated answer!

Comment: thank you very much! your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

[This answer is designed to explain more fully *why* [Florian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56340186/185055) works / is necessary and the wider context of the problem (really two problems) and solutions to it.]

There are two interwined issues here:

1. Creating resource unit agents that have per-unit utilization calculated and accessible.
2. Actually accessing individual resource units. (A **ResourcePool** does not have a `get` function or similar to directly get the agents inside it.)

This is not all explained very clearly in the AnyLogic help.

### Creating Special Resource Unit Agents

Per-resource-unit utilization (as well as other functionality) is available as part of the special resource unit API (Application Programming Interface; basically a set of functions) discussed in the **Library Reference Guides > Process Modeling Library > Resource functions** help page.

*However*, this is only accessible if you create your own custom resource unit agent type; when you create a **Resource Pool**, by default the units therein are vanilla `Agent` objects and do *not* have this special resource unit functionality. (You can get the overall utilization of the *pool* via its `getUtilization` function.)

For the Process Modeling library, you can create a custom type which acts as a resource unit in three ways:

- New --> Agent Type (right-click menu for your model in the Projects palette), specifying `Agent will be used in flowcharts as: Resource Unit`;
- The **Resource Type** element in the Process Modeling Library palette. (This effectively shows the same wizard as the first method but with the use in flowcharts not present and automatically set under the covers.)
- Clicking `create a custom type` when adding a **Resource Pool** (under the `New resource type` setting), which takes you to the same wizard as the second alternative above.

[**Java / Technical Note**: What happens is that you create your own agent type (subclass of `Agent` in Java terminology) which implements the special AnyLogic-provided `IResourceUnit` interface (a Java thing which defines all the special resource unit API functions that are available). This is relevant later...]

### Accessing Individual Resource Units

There are several ways to do this:

(1) In the actions of your **Resource Pool** you have access to the current resource unit via the special keyword `unit`. (Hover over the lightbulb when editing these action boxes to get info on this.) *However*, this just provides them as a vanilla `Agent` (even if it is actually a custom resource unit, let's say of type `MyResourceAgent`).

So you have to **cast** (a Java thing) `unit` to effectively say "I know this is actually a `MyResourceAgent` so let me see it as one of those please"; e.g.,

`((MyResourceAgent) unit).getUtilization()`

(2) As in the the **Library Reference Guides > Process Modeling Library > Resource functions** help page, you have access to all the resource units an agent has seized via that agent's built-in `resourceUnits` collection (list).

However, that again contains them just as Agents, so you have to cast them; e.g.,

`((MyResourceAgent) agent.resourceUnits.get(0)).getUtilization()`

(3) If you set your resource pool up so that its agents are added to a custom population (rather than the 'hidden' default population), you can then access them explicitly at all times via that population.

Following the earlier example, you create an empty population (let's say called `myResourceUnits` for agents of type `MyResourceUnit`) and set the Resource Pool to `Add units to: Custom population` (in its Advanced properties), selecting the population you've set up.

Then you can access individuals via, e.g., `myResourceUnits(0).getUtilization()`.

**NB**: You have to be aware here of what you are doing depending on how you set the `When capacity decreases` setting in your Resource Pool. If you set it to `Units are destroyed` then your population will change size as the pool changes capacity (say via a schedule).

(**Java / Technical Note**: In all the cases above, you can also cast to `IResourceUnit` since that is the interface all custom resource agent types are implementing. But that won't give you access to any functionality you added to your custom resource type such as its own set of parameters.)