# Anylogic Utilization and driven distance for each transporter

Tags: java, anylogic, agent

I am modelling a production system and all orders are moved via AGVs.
At certain times during the simulation model, I would like to log the utlization and driven distance of each agv into a dataset.

When I try to add `AGV.getUtilization()` to my dataset I get the error: `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getUtilization() from the type AGV`.

Now I am a little lost.

Comment: I think the answers to this question should help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56339623/reporting-utilization-of-individual-resourcepool-units

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function for getting a fleet's utilization is just
`transporterFleet.utilization()`

I am not sure what you are referencing when you call `AGV` but it appears to be pointing to the agent type (Since it starts with a uppercaseletter) and not the agent nor the fleet.

Comment: But how do I access it? The name of the transport-agent population is AGV. But I would like to get the utlization and driven distance for each single agent. But I do not know how to access them.

Comment: use AGV.utilization()